# How to align image height with div next to it in Bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align `img` element and `div` element in same line like this:

[image]

(Button should be horizontally aligned with bottom line of image. Top side same)

I want to align them perfectly even in mobile devices(sm, e.g iPad), too

**index.html **

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- IMAGE -->
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <div class="thumbnail relative margin-bottom-3">
            <figure style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
                <img class="img-responsive" id="product-image" src="" alt="shop first image" style="width:610px; height:352px;">
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /IMAGE -->

    <!-- ITEM DESC -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="clearfix margin-bottom-15">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
             {% crispy item_form %}
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /ITEM DESC -->
</div>
```

How could I implement it?

Comment: so what you'r saying, you don't care what the device size really is, even it will apply on device like Iphone 5? i mean the device is really small and your image and your font of the form will be shrink.

Comment: As I said, `sm`, which means small device (tablet PC). So only for `sm`, `md`, `lg` (bootstrap term)

Comment: Small (sm) is mobile, medium (md) is tablet in Bootstrap.

Comment: @user3595632 i know, but if you put it all side by side even in a small device, the viewer has a difficult time to read those. how about you set sm-12, md-6, and lg-6? and about you question, did you already have inspect them? it should be has some margin or padding from bootstrap col that you should improving by yourself.

Comment: @Obink just think about it only in case of `lg`.

Comment: @connexo you're wrong. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: From that page: /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

Comment: @user3595632 did you inspect them? can i see the a image's inspect result?

Comment: @Obink As I said above, 
Button should be horizontally aligned with bottom line of image. Top side same)

Answer (score 0):

ok then, let me try to answer this.

for now let's part from bootstrap and do traditional code. more typing.

```css
section{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
flex-direction:column;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:200px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:1px black solid;}

.withImage{
display:flex;
width:70%;}

.withImage img{
width:100%;}

.withForm{
width:30%;
height:100%;
padding:0;
align-items:center;
position:relative;}

form{
width:100%;
height:100%;}

.withForm ul{
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:center;

}

.withForm li{
width:80%;
}
.withForm li:last-child{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  justify-content:center;
}

.withForm input{
width:50%;
margin:0px;}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content withImage">
    <img src="http://imagecolony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Wallpaper-Wide-803.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content withForm">
    <form>
    <ul>
      <li>text <input type="text" placeholder="sometext"></li>
      <li>text <input type="text" placeholder="sometext"></li>
      <li>text <input type="text" placeholder="sometext"></li>
      <li>text <input type="text" placeholder="sometext"></li>
      <li><input type="submit" placeholder="enter"></li>
    </ul>
      </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

it should be easier if you using flex, and first of all i bet u never inspect your code. if you are using chrome to run your script please right click and inspect, what happened with your css.

you can find it [all about flex in here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

wish it will be help.